# Error while starting WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Using rails(2.3.18) and ruby 1.8.7

Booting WEBrick

`script/server`

Facing issue

```
=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 2.3.18 application starting on localhost:3000

config.load_paths is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths instead
config.load_paths= is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths= instead
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/icicle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/icicle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:104.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#search is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#search called from /home/icicle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:119.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#search is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#search called from /home/icicle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:119.

You're running a version of ruby with no Readline support

Please `gem install rb-readline` or recompile ruby --with-readline.
```

Tried 'gem install rb-readline' but still issue is there.

Comment: Maybe you just follow the instruction of the error message? "Please gem install rb-readline or recompile ruby --with-readline."

Comment: Since it looks like you're using RVM, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8799283/877472), or the one above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you'll need to add this gem to a Gemfile as well. Then run `bundle install`

If you do not have Gemfile, then you'll need to run `rake gems:install` like described in [relevant guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/command_line.html#rake-is-ruby-make)

Comment: Thanks... It works. But why this gem need to do install at my machine only?

Comment: Looks like you're using rvm. So maybe you forget to run ```rvm requirements``` or install some dependencies as stated in rvm's readme... Anyway I suggest not to bother a lot about this and go ahead...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install that missing gem to your system first.

For that you have to run the code in command line 'gem install GEME NAME'

After that still that error comes then you have to add that gem in conf/environment.rb where gem list present because the application has rails 2.3.18.